# how to set kubernetes persistent environment variable

Tags: kubernetes

I want keep version of all pods (App) in env inside namespace. so i can use them in yaml file to create deployment. or even in ci/cd makes devops easier.

right now developer must set the version in yaml file.

Comment: This is a basic use of templating tools like [Helm](https://helm.sh).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the environment variables in menifest file or in yaml file you can simply use the kubernetes `secrets` & `config maps`.

where can store the environment and use them during the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

That's about the design principle, and that's the ideal approach to apply for your pipeline.

You don't have to save the `exact` version of all your Pods inside the manifest file, just use the `latest` or environment-like tag (e.g `staging` or `production`)

And in your pipeline, you could patch the deployment with the corresponding tag based on your build.

One example of this approach:

```
kubectl patch deployment $YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME -p "{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"image\":\"$YOUR_BUILD_STAGE-$PIPELINE_ID\"}},\"spec\":{\"revisionHistoryLimit\":2,\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"name\":\"$YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME\",\"image\":\"$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$YOUR_BUILD_STAGE-$PIPELINE_ID\"}]}}}}"
```